# list/find all regular files in all subdirectories excluding binary files

Tags: linux, find

In Linux.

I know I can do `find . -type f`, but that includes binary file and I couldn't find a way to exclude them with find

Comment: What constitutes "binary"? All files are binary when you get down to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file /usr/bin/file`, for example, does not include the word "binary" in its output on my system. If `file -i` is available, it does include the word "binary". Without `-i`, it may be more reliable to test for the presence of the word "text".

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "file {} | grep text >/dev/null" \; -print
```

or

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "file {} | grep text >/dev/null" \; -ls
```

Using `-i`:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "file -i {} | grep -v binary >/dev/null" \; -print
```

Using `file` is only going to be an approximation since it's using heuristics to determine the type of file and there's no hard-and-fast definition of what constitutes a "binary" file. Is an empty file "binary"? `file` says it is. Also, there are lots of (normally uncommon) ways to trigger false positive IDs by `file`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to exclude all files which have execute permission set for either user, group or others:

```
find . -type f ! -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x
```

(If binary equals execute permissions...)

Comment: That's bad, especially because script files would also be included

Answer (score 0):

show all files without executable permissions (although this is not specifically binary, so it may not be exactly what you need):

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($1 !~ /x/) print $8}'
```

Comment: I thought of a similar thing, but worried that executable != binary. Nevertheless, you can do this just with find as well: `find . -type f \! -executable`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec file "{}" \; | grep -vE "ELF|archive"
```

Comment: you might need `\;` after `"{}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Example using Python and shell:

```
IS_BINARY='import sys; sys.exit(not b"\x00" in open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read())'
find . -type f -exec bash -c "python -c '$IS_BINARY' {} || echo {}" \;
```

The key element is in:

```
b"\x00" in open("foo.bar", "rb").read()
```

which checks if the file has [NULL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean regular files which basically doesn't contain [NULL characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), try using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -PaLr '\x00' .
```